# How to pause/resume procedure while/after upload file by ChannelSftp

Tags: jsch

I am trying to upload file from local disk to remote server by `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(String src, String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor)`

I find that even the upload progress is not completed,if there is no exception occured,program will go ahead.For example,send a message to client that a file already uploaded to server.But the file is still being uploaded,if client try to get the file immediately,the file is a blank file or inconsistent file.

How to pause the main program while uploading file,and resume it once complete upload?

Answer (score 0):

JSch's ChannelSftp does the actual file transfer in a background thread, if you use that [`put` method](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor%29). This is done so your program can do other things during that, or even use the channel to upload or download other stuff.

The [progress monitor](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html) object you did pass will be informed of the progress, and the end of the upload or download.
Use this to know when it is done, or when you can do other things with the file.